# Does Poison's secondary damage only happen once, or does it keep happening?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, poison

Our group is unsure of how poison works in Dungeons and Dragons 3.5e.  Poison says that it does some kind of initial damage, usually to some ability score.  Then it does secondary damage that happens after a minute.  Our question is, does this damage happen once per minute or does it stop after the secondary damage hits once, after that minute.

Comment: The SE format doesn't handle followup questions well. It does, however, handle multiple different questions well - so I recommend you create a new question for that "multiple vials = multiple saving throws" question.

Answer (score 6):

## One need only make 2 saving throws against each poisoning incident

A poison deals its initial damage upon being delivered if the saving throw against it is failed, then, 1 min. later, the poison deals its secondary damage if a second saving throw is failed. But that's *all* the damage it deals; it doesn't *continue* dealing damage thereafter. That's according to [poison](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#poison)

> When a character takes damage from an attack with a poisoned weapon, touches an item smeared with contact poison, consumes poisoned food or drink, or is otherwise poisoned, he must make a Fortitude saving throw. If he fails, he takes the poison’s initial damage (usually ability damage). Even if he succeeds, he typically faces more damage 1 minute later, which he can also avoid with a successful Fortitude saving throw.

Thus, the creature that comes into contact with the poison black lotus extract (Fort DC 20, initial damage 3d6 Con, secondary damage 3d6 Con) must make a Fortitude saving throw (DC 20). Success means no effect. Failure means the creature is dealt 3d6 points of [Constitution damage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#abilityDamage). Then, 1 min. later, the creature who came into contact with the poison black lotus extract makes a second Fortitude saving throw (DC 20). Success means no effect. Failure means the creature is dealt 3d6 points of Constitution damage. No further damage is dealt.

Note that if poisoned multiple times the creature must make saving throws against each incident of poisoning. If a poisonous spider bites a character 5 times, for example, the character must make 10 saving throws against the spider's poison, 1 for each of the initial 5 bites and then 1 for each of the 5 bites 1 min. after each bite.

Comment: I've always assumed the word "typically" means there may be exceptions but that it'd be stated in the creature.  Generally, you'll see primary and secondary poison damage in the stat blocks (like http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ettercap.htm).  I assume if you ever saw just primary or 3 #s, it'd infer different (and hopefully spell that out as well).

Comment: @joedragons I'm certain you're correct. The word *typically* is used there to exempt poisons that deal **no** secondary damage (e.g. dragon bile); I know of no Wizards of the Coast-published poison that deals *tertiary* damage.